# Does use of sleep guarantees execution sequence of a Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Does below code snippet guarantees that t1, T2 and T3 will start executing in sequence?

```
public class ThreadExecDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadDemo(),"t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadDemo(),"t2");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(new ThreadDemo(),"t3");
        t1.start();
        Thread.sleep(5);
        t2.start();
        Thread.sleep(5);
        t3.start();
    }
}

class ThreadDemo implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is running ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sleep is *not* a synchronization primitive.!.!. Purge such thoughts from your mind - now, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: No. You cannot influence the scheduling of threads reliably by sleeping (why would you even want to?).
When you start a thread it runs asynchronously to any other thread (including the main thread) and you have no control over when it is scheduled. Nor should you care.

Answer (score 1):

As @Nathan Hughes said, no, there is no guarantee that the threads will start executing in a sequence.

Reasoning: **Sleep()** blocks the current thread for the number of timeslices that can occur within the specified number of milliseconds. However, the length of a timeslice is actually different on certain versions of Windows or Processors. As a result, **Sleep()** is not useful for timing or, in your case, trying to execute threads in a specific sequence

Try to avoid using **Sleep()**
 - in my opinion, Sleep is only useful for simulating lengthy or calculation intensive operations while testing/debugging

Comment: This is a Java question.

Comment: It still answers the question... I will remove irrelevant information though. Thanks for the heads up @VGR

Comment: now everything in the answer is completely relevant to java (letting future readers know)

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment yet so posting here: there is actually quite a decent stack overflow answer about executing threads in sequence here [running 3 threads in sequence java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989397/running-3-threads-in-sequence-java)

Check the generic solution with "class RunThreadsInOrder" does what you want using synchronized lock.

Comment: While that link may provide an answer to the question, it would be ideal if you could provide a relevant summary, with proper attribution. Otherwise, your answer may turn invalid or useless if the link becomes broken or the page's content changes.