# Print integers from 1 to 10 with only 5 Threads in a specific order

Tags: java, multithreading

**I have recently started with multi-threading in Java**

I have an issue solving a problem where I have got only 5 **Threads** ranging from ***T1, T2,...T5***.

The task is to print numbers from 1 to 10 in the following order.

```
T1 -> 1
T2 -> 2
T3 -> 3
T4 -> 4
T5 -> 5
T1 -> 6
T2 -> 7
T3 -> 8
T4 -> 9
T5 -> 10
```

I tried solving it with this piece of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    Thread[] tArray = new Thread[] { new Thread(counter, "T1"), new Thread(counter, "T2"),
            new Thread(counter, "T3"), new Thread(counter, "T4"), new Thread(counter, "T5") };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i < 5) {
            tArray[i].start();
            tArray[i].join();
        } else {
            tArray[i - 5] = new Thread(counter, "T" + ((i - 5) + 1)); //Instantiating new Thread which is not allowed.
            tArray[i - 5].start();
            tArray[i - 5].join();
        }
    }
}

public class Counter implements Runnable {

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -> " + ++count);
    }

}
```

But since only 5 threads are allowed my solution is not accepted since I am also instantiating `new Thread` in the `else` block of the `for` loop.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, this is pretty much a dup of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989397/running-3-threads-in-sequence-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to arrange interaction between threads. The most natural way for thread interaction is setting up blocking queues which connect threads. Queues can be independent objects, or belong to particular threads. 
In your case, you need to make a circle of 5 threads.

```
class CountPrinter extends Thread {
   String name;
   ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> inp = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>();
   CountPrinter next;

   public void run() {
      for (;;)
         int n = inp.take();
         if (n == 11) {// only 10 numbers must be printed
            next.inp.put(11);
            return;
         }
         System.out.println(name+"->"+n);
         next.inp.put(n+1);
      }
   }
}
```

After creating a thread and before its start, you need to assign the fields `name` and `next`. I believe you can program this yourself.
Also, the first thread must be provided with the initial value `1`.

Comment: This is much nicer than the other answers (including mine!).

Comment: This is nice and crisp. Will test it.

Comment: I like this solution as well.

Comment: This worked well. Thanks @Alexei

Comment: A couple of updates. Thread class `name` can be reused. `new ArrayBlockingQueue<>();` should be `new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);`

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Disclaimer: I am answering the practical counterpart of the OP's question — parallel processing with serial input and output. It's much more fun.</sub>

#### Thinking process

1. I have a serial resource - `System.out`. No matter how I structure the code there will be explicit or implicit queueing/contention in front of it.
2. The best way to deal with contention is via explicit queueing (which can be observed, quantified, and addressed, opposed to when implicit queue on a mutex or a synchronized block is used).
3. My is a 3 step pipeline: `Produce`→`Stringize`→`Output`.
4. The `Stringize` step can be done in parallel, providing that the ordered `Output` can still happen.
5. I start from a quick & dirty "poor man's" solution. With `Java 8` this would be with `CompletableFuture`-s:

   ```
   final Executor inputWorker = newSingleThreadExecutor();
   final Executor processingPool = newFixedThreadPool(3);
   final Executor outputWorker = newSingleThreadExecutor();

   final int[] counter = {-1}; // this emulates a non-thread-safe information source
   CompletableFuture<Void> future = completedFuture(null);
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
       future = future // chaining of futures is essential for serializing subsequent iterations
               .thenApplyAsync(unused -> ++counter[0], inputWorker)
               .thenApplyAsync(Objects::toString, processingPool)
               .thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println, outputWorker);
   }
   future.join();
   ```
6. Once I have good intuition how it works I may consider industrial techniques like [actors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), [disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor), or something alike to improve it further.

P.S. - for completeness, one may want to have step #5 slightly differently, first  create the whole computation schedule and then trigger it:

```
final Executor producer = newSingleThreadExecutor();
final Executor stringizer = newFixedThreadPool(3);
final Executor printer = newSingleThreadExecutor();

final int[] counter = {-1}; // this emulates a non-thread-safe information source

System.out.println("creating schedule...");
// first schedule the whole amount of work and block the execution on a single "trigger" future
final CompletableFuture<Void> trigger = new CompletableFuture<>();
CompletableFuture<Void> future = trigger;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    future = future
            .thenApplyAsync(unused -> ++counter[0], producer)
            .thenApplyAsync(Objects::toString, stringizer)
            .thenAcceptAsync(System.out::println, printer);
}

// then pull the trigger
System.out.println("pulling the trigger...");
trigger.complete(null);
future.join();
```

Comment: Isn't the use of a threadpool for the stringification redundant when you're going to `join()` after each step?

Comment: @ohlec - I knew someone would notice! I reworked it, please read again :-)

Comment: OK, but don't you now get race conditions and lose ordering?

Comment: @ohlec - no race condition and loss of ordering because the last step of an iteration _happens before_ the first step of the next iteration because of the future chaining, agree?

Comment: Ah, yes, I overlooked the part of the edit where you chain futures across for loop iterations, sorry. This is a very sensible solution. (I'm afraid it still doesn't fit the original requirements because the threads have different tasks now, though)

Comment: @ohlec - I spent a fair amount of (paid) time fixing software implemented to the requirements similar to the ones in the question, so would rather not advise in that direction :-) They should really stop teaching threads and low level primitives before teaching executors, pipelines, flow graphs, and actors.

Comment: I get that you are demonstrating that there are better ways of achieving parallelism than using low level synchronization primitives, but I think you'd fail the homework assignment.

Comment: @MalcolmSmith - thanks mate, you also paid attention to the disclaimer at the top, before downvoting, yeah?

Comment: @bobah in hindsight the down vote was unnecessary. Unfortunately I can't take it back now :(

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to keep two `AtomicInteger`s , something like this:

```
static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final AtomicInteger index;
    private final AtomicInteger ai;
    private final int[] array;
    private final int current;
    private final int next;

    public MyRunnable(AtomicInteger index, AtomicInteger ai, int[] array, int current, int next) {
        this.index = index;
        this.ai = ai;
        this.array = array;
        this.current = current;
        this.next = next;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            if (index.get() == array.length) {
                break;
            }
            if (ai.get() == current) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + array[index.getAndIncrement()]);
                ai.compareAndSet(current, next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And usage would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger(1);
    AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger(0);

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(index, ai, array, 1, 2), "T1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(index, ai, array, 2, 3), "T2");
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(index, ai, array, 3, 4), "T3");
    Thread t4 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(index, ai, array, 4, 5), "T4");
    Thread t5 = new Thread(new MyRunnable(index, ai, array, 5, 1), "T5");

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
    t5.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow your 5 threads to communicate so that they run in a strict sequence. Kind of like dominos falling, each thread must sit waiting until it is poked, then it does its thing and says to the next thread 'You can go now'.

But unlike dominos falling they must also pick themselves back up so they are ready for the next round, and the last domino must knock over the first domino again!

I think the best built-in for this kind of communication is the `Phaser`. Here is an implementation using Phasers:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public final class SequencedThreads
{
    private static AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintThread[] threads = new PrintThread[5];

        // Create our 5 threads, each with a phaser waiting on itself 
        // and the previous thread
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            threads[i] = new PrintThread("T" + (i + 1));
            if(i > 0)
                threads[i - 1].next = threads[i].phaser;
        }

        // Join the last thread back to the first thread
        threads[4].next = threads[0].phaser;

        // Start our threads
        for(PrintThread pt : threads)
            pt.start();

        // Trigger the first thread to print
        threads[0].phaser.arriveAndDeregister();
    }

    private static final class PrintThread extends Thread {
        Phaser phaser;
        Phaser next;

        public PrintThread(String name) {
            super(name);
            this.phaser = new Phaser(2);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                // Block until we are poked
                phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
                int newCount = count.incrementAndGet();
                if(newCount > 10) {
                    // We are done, but trigger the other threads to allow 
                    // the JVM to exit
                    next.arriveAndDeregister();
                    return;
                }

                System.out.println(getName() + " -> " + newCount);
                // Pick ourselves back up
                phaser.register();
                // Poke the next domino
                next.arriveAndDeregister();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    class LocalTask extends Thread {

        public static final int TOTAL = 5;

        private final int a;
        private final int b;
        private final AtomicInteger lock;

        public LocalTask(int id, AtomicInteger lock) {
            super("T" + id);
            a = id;
            b = id + TOTAL;
            this.lock = lock;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    synchronized (lock) {
                        int count = lock.get();
                        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();

                        if (count == a)
                            System.out.println(name + " -> " + a);
                        else if (count == b)
                            System.out.println(name + " -> " + b);
                        else
                            continue;

                        lock.incrementAndGet();
                        lock.notifyAll();

                        if (count == a)
                            lock.wait();
                        else
                            return;
                    }
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    AtomicInteger lock = new AtomicInteger(1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= LocalTask.TOTAL; i++)
        new LocalTask(i, lock).start();
}
```